# confusing words with operators in excel and python

Tags: python, excel, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm using Python 2.7, mechanize and BeautifulSoup to retrieve data from Excel spreadsheets.

The data consists of words in French, and the word 'or' (French for 'gold') keeps getting confused with the logical operator OR, and my code crashes since it doesn't read it as a string.

Is there a way to detect if something is a logical operator in Python? so that I could then replace it with the string 'or'?

Comment: What is the error that you get related to `or` operator ?

Comment: There's no way that can happen unless you use `input` or `eval` in some form.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.

I was getting 

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'replace'

because at some point I was replacing stuff in my strings. But indeed it was not a problem with 'or'. It actually turns out that some intern kept inserting TRUE in some cells by accident... I have no clue how this happened, all I know is that even microsoft excel can be a challenge to some psychiatry interns...

Comment: Whenever you use a phrase that can be confused with an operator, try using the str() function so that it won't recognize it incorrectly. Tell me if this helps!